# Bash script that updates self?

Tags: bash, self-updating

I'm writing a utility using Bash scripting and I'd like to include an update feature with it. The script currently follows Ruby's gem philosophy, eg one command with multiple subcommands:

```
gem help
gem version
gem update
```

Ideally you would run:

```
myscript update
```

But I don't know if this is possible.

What's the best method of going about this? I know that writing to the currently running script is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to write to the currently running script?

Comment: @user unknown: it depends on how you're writing, the semantics of your filesystem, and the implementation of your shell. Suppose your shell is reading instructions from the file one at a time and you manage to modify the file in such a way that the file it's interpreting has changed out from under it. It may continue executing at a different place, part-way through an instruction, or even past the end of the file.

Comment: Doesn't the shell load the whole script into memory, before executing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply invoke `wget` to download the new version. After successful download, move it to the current script's location and `chmod +x` it.

Comment: +1. I'd probably `chmod +x` it first, and then `exec mv` it. Probably overkill, but would make me sleep easier. :-)

Comment: This results in an empty file

Comment: Ugh, scratch that, issues with the website :)